# Google maps api v3 not loading in maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem with google maps, I have tried to just to set up a normal map, but nothing works all I get is this image: 
[image]

And this is my code for this:

```js
(function ($) {
    var marker;
    var map;
    var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/';
    var infowindow;

    function initialize() {

        getCoordinate(function (location) {
            setUpMap(location.latitude, location.longitude);
        });


    }

    function setUpMap(lat, long)
    {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false,
            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
        codeAddress();
    }
    function codeAddress()
    {
        //Resellers is a global varaible that holds all the resellers addresses
        Object.keys(resellers).forEach(function(key){
            var reseller = resellers[key];
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(reseller.lat, reseller.lng),
                icon: iconBase + 'green-dot.png'
            });
            (function (marker) {
                // add click event
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                    if (infowindow) {
                        infowindow.close();
                    }
                    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        title: key,
                        content: '<div style="color: black; height: 150px;">' + reseller.address + '</div>'
                    });
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker);
            gmaerksp.push(marker);
        });
    }



    function getCoordinate(callback) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            function (position) {
                var returnValue = {
                    latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                    longitude: position.coords.longitude
                };
                var location = returnValue;
              

                callback(location);
            }
        );
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

}(jQuery));
```

```css
#map-canvas{
   width: 1200px;
   height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

And I have no idea why the map is not loading, the markers is loading as it should. But as you can see, the zoom tools is not correctly loading either. So you guys have any idea what is wrong? I have tested with change the div size to but it still loads the same.

Comment: Seems to [work](http://jsfiddle.net/tive/vs8cnvv6/) for me but we're missing the `resellers` object so no markers.

Comment: And it fails miserably if the user has disabled geolocation.

Comment: Yeh I know that it gonna fails, i haven't build in the check for this, and haven't build in default locations.

But i'm starting to figure this out, I think it is something wrong with the way i'm i'm calling this file, at the moment I run this in a shortcode in wordpress. So i'm gonna try some other diffrent ways to see if that does any change

Answer (score 0):

Well after more debugging, I found the answer! It seems like google maps can't be inserted with wordpress shortcode. I don't know why, but as soon as I move it out to it is own template instead it works like a charm.

So if any other persons have the same problem out there, and have put there google maps in a shortcode, try to move it out from there and see if it works.